# Why are my simple date calculations sometimes failing in Swift 3.1?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, nsdate, nscalendar

I have a unit test that looks like this:

```
  func testManyYearsAgo() {
    for year in 2...77 {
      let earlierTime = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: 0 - year, to: now)
//      print(year)
//      print(dateDifference.itWasEstimate(baseDate: now, earlierDate: earlierTime!))
      XCTAssertEqual(dateDifference.itWasEstimate(baseDate: now, earlierDate: earlierTime!), "\(year) years ago")
    }
  }
```

`now` is defined higher up as just `Date()`
`calendar` is `Calendar.current`

It's testing a class that looks something like this:

```
class DateDifference {
  func itWasEstimate(baseDate: Date, earlierDate: Date) -> String {

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let requestedComponent: Set<Calendar.Component> = [ .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
    let timeDifference = calendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: baseDate, to: earlierDate)

    if timeDifference.year! < 0 {
      if timeDifference.year! == -1 {
        return "Last year"
      } else {
        return "\(abs(timeDifference.year!)) years ago"
      }
    }

    return ""
  }
}
```

When I run the unit test, I usually (but not always) get an error like:

```
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("30 years ago") is not equal to ("31 years ago")
```

Those errors usually begin after the year value is over 12.

If I uncomment out the print statements, it works fine no matter how many times I run the code.

This lends me to believe that maybe there's some weird async thing going on, but I sure can't tell by looking. I'm relatively new to swift development, so there may just be something fundamental that I'm missing.

Comment: It's late, and I may just be overlooking something stupidly obvious.

Comment: I copied your code into a playground I am seeing intermittent results too. Sometimes it works properly and sometimes it shows the 1-year difference for some years. Very strange. BTW - you only need to use `.year` for the list of date components.

Comment: Can also reproduce. I *assume* that comes from rounding errors in the calendar calculations (`Date` stores a double with sub-second resolution internally). You could try to normalize `now` to full seconds before doing the calculations. This might also be worth a bug report at Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a self-contained reproducible example demonstrating the 
problem:

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = calendar
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

let d1 = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2017, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 0,
                        minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 456 * Int(NSEC_PER_MSEC)).date!
print("d1:", formatter.string(from: d1))

let d2 = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: -20, to: d1)!
print("d2:", formatter.string(from: d2))

let comps: Set<Calendar.Component> = [ .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond]
let diff = calendar.dateComponents(comps, from: d1, to: d2)
print(diff)
print("difference in years:", diff.year!)
```

Output

```
d1: 2017-01-01 01:00:00.456
d2: 1997-01-01 01:00:00.456
year: -19 month: -11 day: -30 hour: -23 minute: -59 second: -59 nanosecond: -999999756 isLeapMonth: false 
difference in years: -19
```

Due to rounding errors (`Date` uses a binary floating point number as 
internal representation), the difference is computed as a tiny bit
less than 20 years, and the years component of the difference comes out as -19 instead of the expected -20.

As a workaround, you can round the dates to full seconds,
that seems to fix the issue:

```
    let baseDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: baseDate
        .timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.rounded())
    let earlierDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: earlierDate
        .timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.rounded())
```

You might also consider to file a bug report at Apple.

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to the proper and current method of reporting a potential bug like this to Apple? Something on Swift's github maybe?

Comment: Calendar and Date are wrappers for NSCalendar/NSDate from the Foundation framework, therefore bugreporter.apple.com seems the right place to me.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little debugging and found that sometimes, `timeDifference` is off by 1 day.

What I did was I put this line after the initialization of `timeDifference`:

```
print("\(timeDifference.year!) \(timeDifference.month!) \(timeDifference.day!)")
```

The expected output was something like this

```
-2 0 0
-3 0 0
-4 0 0
-5 0 0
-6 0 0
-7 0 0
...
```

However, the actual output contains something like:

```
-38 0 0
-38 -11 -30
-39 -11 -30
-40 -11 -30
...
-55 -11 -30
-57 0 0
```

Apparently in some years, `month` and `day` becomes `-11` and `-30` respectively.

How do you fix this?

Unfortunately, I cannot find the root cause of this issue. However, I have come up with a brute force solution:

```
if timeDifference.year! < 0 {
    if timeDifference.year! == -1 {
        return "Last year"
    } else {
        if timeDifference.month == -11 && timeDifference.day == -30 {
            return "\(abs(timeDifference.year!) + 1) years ago"
        } else {
            return "\(abs(timeDifference.year!)) years ago"
        }
    }
}
```

I check whether the time difference is off by 1 day. If it is, add 1 to the abs of `year`.